# How to isolate the text from a bitmap logo?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, logo

I have been given a logo from a client that they want me to 'extract' or 'cut' the text out of and use just the text with a transparent background to fit with the design ethos of their marketing.

I'm using Photoshop CS6 and have tried using channels, magic wand and eraser but I can't get clean edges on the text.

I'm pretty new to Photoshop and any help appreciated.

[image: Basically they want me to cut out the word 'patagonia', keep it white and have it sit on a transparent background on their marketing material]

Comment: Hi and welcom to Graphic Design.SE. Could you please provide a sample image showing the logo and also showing your result? This makes it easier to help you. Also [this previous answer](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/a/4505/8845) may help you.

Comment: Hi, i've added the image, they basically want to use the word 'patagonia' on a transparent background, but I don't know hw to cut it out cleanly?

Comment: The font Patagonia uses is called [Belwe Bold](http://www.myfonts.com/fonts/bitstream/belwe/bold/), just in case it helps! You can also use an existing but different version of the [logo](http://www.spthree.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/06/Patagonia-logo2.jpg) and use blending modes to make the white 'transparent'

Comment: I suggest you may do it again. The font used seems to be *Belwe*. That may be the easiest and fastest way.

Comment: @Yisela I just realised you beat me to the punch :) you font ninja!

Comment: Many times a company will supply you with a logo pack and brand manual, if you ask. This saves them from having their trademarks represented outside of their wishes. You can also usually find a vector logo in `.pdf`s (catalogs, press releases) on the web if the company is slow to respond.

Comment: Thanks for all your advice, it has all been very helpful! Plenty for me to look into and certainly enough for me to crack on with the project.

Comment: This technique would also work for this. http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/10964/noise-filter-effect-with-transparency/10965#10965 ( By the way, I was able to google really big patagonia logo image. Bigger is better when you are removing background )

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The easiest way would of course be to try and find the typeface the text is set in, and reproduce the word. Barring that possibility, you could try the following:

- Make your image a regular layer (as in: not the background)
- Use the Magic Wand tool set to a somewhat generous tolerance (~32) and select all of the white letterforms (use <kbd>shift</kbd>)+click to add to your selection).
- Click on the 'Add layer mask' button to make your selection into a mask for the layer. You'll find the button on the bottom om the layers panel.

This will yield your text, with some darkish edges where the Magic Wand took along some black pixels and made them partially opaque:

[image: dark edges on text]

- Then, add a color overlay in white to your layer. You can reach the color overlay by right-clicking on the layer in the layers palette and choosing 'Blending options'. To edit the colour and the settings of the overlay, remember to click on the 'color overlay' word on the left-hand list, not just the checkmark.

This will cover all of the visible pixels of the layer in white, leaving the partial transparency of the greyish edges intact, but making them white:

[image: dark edges removed from text]

Answer (score 3):

The font is [Belwe Bold](http://www.myfonts.com/fonts/bitstream/belwe/bold/)  so that should save you from selection issues :)

But for future reference with this sort of problem you can see the answer to this [question](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/25400/issues-using-selection-tool/25408#25408) where a person was having similar issues with selection.

To summarize, you could use the [pen tool](http://www.melissaevans.com/tutorials/how-to-use-photoshops-pen-tool) & convert the [path](http://helpx.adobe.com/photoshop/using/editing-paths.html) to a selection. Or make a [vector mask.](http://helpx.adobe.com/photoshop/using/masking-layers-vector-masks.html)

These are effective and quick. There is also the option of using the [polygonal lasso tool](http://www.photoshopessentials.com/basics/selections/polygonal-lasso-tool/) (L)

If you choose to use the [quick selection tool](http://www.photoshopessentials.com/basics/selections/quick-selection-tool/) or [magic wand tool](http://www.photoshopessentials.com/basics/selections/magic-wand-tool/) (W) then be sure to consider your **tolerance** which is discussed in the links given as well as some great pointers from Bakabaka.

Good luck with your project.

Comment: Thanks for your help, I'm going to look into all techniques and it really helps my learning!

Answer (score 2):

Here's one way to get the edges done perfectly:

1. If necessary, adjust color levels to make the text and background pure white and pure black respectively.  In this case, they're already pretty close, but this would be important if the text or background were gray or colored.
2. Copy the text into the clipboard.
3. Create a new layer filled with solid color (say, black).
4. Add a layer mask for the new layer and paste the text you copied *into the mask*.  (To edit the mask, select it in the Layers dialog.)
5. Optionally, apply the layer mask.

I've tested this method in GIMP, and got the following result:

[image: result]

As far as I can tell, the steps above should work the same way in Photoshop too.

Answer (score -1):

Use the color range and select just the white, then it will automatically select anything white.  Anything around it delete

Comment: Thanks, but I did try that but it doesn't leave clean edges?